# Netlogo: I can move-to expect agent, but got nobody once in a while

Tags: netlogo

With regards to this question [MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938534/move-to-expected-input-to-be-an-agent-but-got-nobody-instead), I regularly encounter the same issue, however, even if I write a `move-to` that is protected by an `if any?`.

Imagine the following scenario, I have two `breed`, and one is ask to approach a member of the other breed if conditions are met. This is what `breed1` executes:

```
if any? breed2 [
    ifelse var >= 5 [
      move-to one-of breed2 in-radius 2
    ]
    [ ... ] 
  ]
```

If, breed2 is not `in-radius` or no member of breed1 has a `var` above 5, I get the above mentioned error message. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `move-to` is NOT protected by an `if any?` clause. The `if` checks whether there are any turtles of breed2, regardless of their distance, but your `move-to` requires there to be one within a certain distance.